# How to make Android method work recurrently?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have designed an app that displays text when tapped once and displays it differently on a Long Press and on a Double Tap. However, I observe that the methods are called once. That is once I either long press or tap once or double tap, the corresponding method is called and then on subsequent tapping or press does not do anything. What can be done to make the app work not just once?

```
package com.example.hello;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener;
import android.view.GestureDetector.OnGestureListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.View.OnLongClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnTouchListener {

    private TextView shownamecenter; 
    private TextView shownamecustom; 
    private RelativeLayout myimage; 
    int x, y;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        shownamecenter = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.shownamecenter);
        shownamecustom = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.shownamecustom);
        myimage = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.myimage);
        shownamecenter.setText("");
        shownamecustom.setText("");
        myimage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showNameOnSingleTap();
                return;

            }
        });; 

        myimage.setOnTouchListener(this); //{



        myimage.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                showNameInCustomPosition(shownamecustom, x, y);// TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return true;
            }
        });


        return;
    }





        private void showNameOnSingleTap() {
            Timer countdown = new Timer(false);
            countdown.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            shownamecenter.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }
                    });
                }
            },3000);

            shownamecustom.setText("");
            shownamecenter.setText("My Text");
            shownamecenter.setTextColor(0xff00ff00);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutparameters = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)shownamecenter.getLayoutParams();
            layoutparameters.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, -1);
            shownamecenter.setLayoutParams(layoutparameters);



            findViewById(R.id.myimage).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    shownamecenter.setText("");

                    return;

                }
            });
            return;




        }

        private void showNameInCustomPosition(TextView customview, int x, int y) {
            Timer countdown = new Timer(false);
            countdown.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            shownamecustom.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }
                    });
                }
            },3000);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relout = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) customview.getLayoutParams();
            relout.leftMargin = x-50;
            relout.topMargin = y-50;
            customview.setLayoutParams(relout);
            shownamecenter.setText("");
            shownamecustom.setText("My Text");
            shownamecustom.setTextColor(0xff00ff00);

            class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
                @Override
                public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
                    shownamecustom.setText("");
                    showNameOnSingleTap();
                    return true;
                }

            }
            return;

        }











    //}


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        x = (int)event.getRawX();
        y = (int)event.getRawY();

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to show some code.What have you done?

Comment: Thanks for that. I have edited my question with the code.

Comment: You are welcome.Now, the masters can come in and help :p

Comment: `shownamecustom`  is the view object you are dealing with? and it is not showing right?

Comment: I am getting the method calls exactly once when I use the emulator. Say for example, myimage.setOnClickListener and myimage.setOnLongClickListener are called exactly once when I emulate. For example, Once I long press, I get the desired behavior, but again long pressing does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you are redefining what happens when you click on the image, which isn't terribly good practice because it makes it difficult to keep track of what should be going on. A View can only ever have one Listener of each type, so when you do

```
private void showNameOnSingleTap() {
    //... 
    findViewById(R.id.myimage).setOnClickListener   (new View.OnClickListener() {   
        @Override public void onClick(View v) {             
            shownamecenter.setText(""); return; 
        } 
    });
}
```

You are changing what happens every time that you click the image after that. Rather than calling your method `showNameOnSingleTap()` when it's clicked, it is only setting the text and not calling your method. Instead of reassigning the onClickListener, just keep a boolean variable to determine what you want to do.

```
boolean textIsVisible = false;
private void showNameOnSingleTap() {
    if(textIsVisible) {
        //hide text
        textIsVisible = false;
        shownamecenter.setText(View.INVISIBLE);
    } 
    else {
        Timer countdown = new Timer(false);
        countdown.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        shownamecenter.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        textIsVisible = false;
                    }
                });
            }
        },3000);
        //show text
        textIsVisible = true;
    } 
}
```

Comment: But, I need to also see if the user clicks again when the image is being displayed before it vanishes. So, what do you suggest?

Comment: And do you mean the second myimage.setOnClickListener is called everytime which does not allow the text to be displayed? The one in the showNameOnSingleTap method?

Comment: That's exactly what happens, the first `onClickListener` goes away and is replaced by the second, so only the code in the second Listener is executed. And I'll update the answer to reflect the click only while the text is visible